# Create pivot table in R

Tags: r, sum, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table in R.

I know there are many different questions for similar issues, but I have tried their solutions and they don't seem to work.

So, can you please help me get from this data frame

| Species | Station1 | Station2 | Station3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Species1 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| Species2 | 10 | 52 | 0 |
| Species4 | 0 | 3 | 8 |
| Species2 | 20 | 15 | 5 |
| Species3 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| Species2 | 6 | 9 | 2 |
| Species1 | 5 | 10 | 5 |

To this data frame

| Species | Station1 | Station2 | Station3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Species1 | 10 | 15 | 10 |
| Species2 | 36 | 76 | 7 |
| Species4 | 0 | 3 | 8 |
| Species3 | 4 | 5 | 5 |

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It would appear us base R users are becoming a dying breed on SO. Here's a one line solution without the addition of any extra packages.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "Species    Station1    Station2    Station3
Species1    5   5   5
Species2    10  52  0
Species4    0   3   8
Species2    20  15  5
Species3    4   5   5
Species2    6   9   2
Species1    5   10  5", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)

aggregate(. ~ Species, data = xy, FUN = sum)

    Species Station1 Station2 Station3
1 Species1        10       15       10
2 Species2        36       76        7
3 Species3         4        5        5
4 Species4         0        3        8
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I was lost in the (too many) different packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~Species, ~Station1, ~Station2, ~Station3,
  "Species1",   5,  5,  5,
  "Species2",   10, 52, 0,
  "Species4",   0,  3,  8,
  "Species2",   20, 15, 5,
  "Species3",   4,  5,  5,
  "Species2",   6,  9,  2,
  "Species1",   5,  10, 5
)

df %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), sum))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Species  Station1 Station2 Station3
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Species1       10       15       10
2 Species2       36       76        7
3 Species3        4        5        5
4 Species4        0        3        8
```